# There is Hardware, Software, Firmware and ...FPGAware?

Tags: fpga, firmware

I think by this day and age we all probably have a pretty good understanding of the distinction between hardware and software. In addition it is widely accepted that firmware is software that is injected into an embedded system in a way that it is not readily changeable for each time you power up and run such system.

Many designs of systems use FPGA components that are "programmable" in the sense that they load an image from some non-volatile FLASH memory at power up that configures the FPGA to perform some intended functionality in the system. My question here is what is the generally accepted name for the FPGA data collateral that defines its functionality? As you can see in the title I have made up the loose term FPGAware but I rather doubt that it is the term really in use.

For purposes of this question let us consider that the FPGA consists of basic logic that includes gates, flip flops, registers, sequencers and state machines. The FPGA would NOT include a fixed or synthesized processor core that runs some "software".

Comment: What's wrong with FPGA code or FPGA design, it doesn't have to end in ware. If you start giving it a name like FPGAware software engineers may think they design hardware and that never ends well.

Comment: The files are normally referred to as a "bitstream", although it can also be called firmware.

Comment: @Andrew - I am certainly not looking for anything that ends in 'ware. I am looking for a word that captures a name for this type of collateral that is not a mouthful and at the same time understandable. FPGA code comes close but it does not seem to capture the true essence that I am after.

Comment: "Al dente-ware"?

Comment: I use "FPGA Desing" or "Hardware Design" to describe the activity, depending on the company. For the result, I use either "Firmware" (which is a language abuse, but very popular term in the industry) or "bitstream". I don't like "FPGA Code", or any software term as it confuses managers...

Comment: I hereby propose config, gate config, array config, or gate array config (GARC for short). >:]

Comment: We often call it 'the VHDL' (other hardware description languages are available). To add to the other 'wares, there's glassware (stuff that breaks easily), stiffware (stuff for which you've lost the source code), wetware (humans), vapourware (what software marketing people try to sell you), shelfware (stuff you've bought, but never used), I won't go on.

Comment: Go for register-transfer-level-ware.

Comment: I've used both firmware, and FPGA image.

Comment: 1 vote for firmware, its still flash on most FPGA's afterall

Comment: @laptop2d - "most FPGA's" ?? Many FPGAs internally hold all their internal configuration in RAM cells. Those RAM cells get loaded by some access to an external source of data. Often that data comes from an external SPI Flash chip that is next to the FPGA,

Comment: @MichaelKaras Thats exaclty what I mean when I say they use flash, thanks for proving my point.

Comment: @laptop2d - I didn't prove any point that you had. You said that there was flash on most FPGAs and I made the point that this was not necessarily the case.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Most of Lattice, microsemi make FPGA's with internal flash. Most of Xilinx lower end and Altera's mid and lower end use internal flash. Higher end doesn't, maybe you only design with higher end FPGA's?

Comment: @laptop2d - I tend to design with higher density FPGAs because that us where the density of complex boards can be realized with lots of I/O pins. The lower density parts are used sometimes, in particular where instant ON configuration is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a project, engineers typically call a functional unit by its function. If they have a baseband processor in programmable logic, they will call it "the baseband". Likewise for modems, rf frontends, crypto-cores, network processors etc. Firmware is by no way "firm" in the development process. Exactly this is what makes programmable logic so attractive for development.

The software vs firmware vs hardware distinction is more about how easily a unit can be replaced in the field. Since FPGA-bitstreams are often stored together with other firmware in non-volatile memory, its OK to also call it firmware ... since the process to update it is the same from a user perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Software is binaries that are "soft" they live in ram and are lost when the power goes out, you load then when you use them, discard them when you are done.

Firmware is a bit more "firm" than software, it tends to be programmed once and stays there, is always used, not loaded and discarded, not temporary, it is more firm than software.

The bits that are used in a flash next to the fpga to make it work are no different than the bits in the flash next to some other chip, both are firmware.  Because they are firm, not soft.

The programming languages are programming languages I dont have a problem calling vhdl nor verilog a programming language because it is.  Some folks want to say hdl or rtl instead and that is just fine too to describe the source code just like saying python or C or high level programming language.  Nothing wrong with saying FPGA code or FPGA source code either.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure if you are asking about what to call it prior to synthesis or post synthesis, so I'll add my 2p worth for both.

Prior to synthesis, you have either have code based or schematic based hardware descriptions or a mixture depending on which you prefer. These are what I would simply call **"source code"**, **"source files"** or just **"code"**.

Once synthesised you have what I would call simply **"firmware"**. The compiled bitstreams or object files are no different from the machine code files that would be used for an embedded processor. They would both be considered firmware in the sense that they are permanently compiled and stored into what is essentially a read-only state. It really doesn't make much difference to the definition that one contains machine instructions while the other contains initialisation information for the various LUTs and memories in the FPGA.

I would also go one step further though and distinguish fully compiled complete firmware (that you can upload as is to the FPGA) from its building blocks. The building blocks of the firmware are typically referred to as **"IP cores"**. These can be pure source code, or fully synthesized **"netlists"** which can be integrated as part of a larger design. This is pretty much akin to libraries in the software world.

---

As a side note, I've personally never heard of the term FPGAware, nor would I ever use it - even the thought of its existence makes me cringe.

Answer (score 1):

"Gateware" is one term I have seen used.

But to me, it's all firm/software - it can be changed. It happens to configure some hardware elements, but key to me is that it provides functionality and that functionality is not fixed. (Having said that, I see others' point that calling it "software" implies some things that are not valid to people less familiar with FPGAs...)

Answer (score 0):

Just like Tom Carpenter, in the pre-compiled state, the description is simply "code", "source code".

For the/synthesized thing that you load onto your FPGA, I'd say "Configuration", because *configure* is the verb commonly used for the process of loading the "FPGA image" (another term that describes the configuration in their stored state) onto the FPGA.

We often speak about *designs*, which is kind of nice, because it highlights the fact that, just like a schematic and board layout leading to a PCB design, HDL / visual design approaches lead to an FPGA configuration.